# Query whether file exists in different application

Tags: android

I have I have two applications. I have a menu button on one application (service A) that is used to trigger an action in a different service (service B).

I want to make the menu item (service A) visible only if a file is present in service B.

Is there a clean mechanism for achieving this, rather than using absolute paths with File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Use remote binding across services. You'd need to define an interface using [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) and then invoke methods on the interface to delegate the responsibility for checking if the file exists to service B.
2. Define a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in the application that "owns" the file and query the content provider to see whether the file exists or not.